# Storing integer values from lines of text in a .txt file

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors, fgets, scanf

I'm trying to store 10 integers from the second and third lines of a text file into an array of integers. When I try to compile, I get multiple errors about certain variables being undeclared.

Input is the name assigned to the Input .txt file.

perm1 and perm2 are both int arrays of size [10].

```
int current_line = 0; //a line counter
while(fgets(line, 401, Input) != NULL){
  if(current_line == 1){
    sscanf(line, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4, &n5, &n6, &n7, &n8, &n9, &n10);
    perm1[0] = n1;
    perm1[1] = n2;
    perm1[2] = n3;
    perm1[3] = n4;
    perm1[4] = n5;
    perm1[5] = n6;
    perm1[6] = n7;
    perm1[7] = n8;
    perm1[8] = n9;
    perm1[9] = n10;
  }
  else if(current_line == 2){
    sscanf(line, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4, &n5, &n6, &n7, &n8, &n9, &n10);
    perm2[0] = n1;
    perm2[1] = n2;
    perm2[2] = n3;
    perm2[3] = n4;
    perm2[4] = n5;
    perm2[5] = n6;
    perm2[6] = n7;
    perm2[7] = n8;
    perm2[8] = n9;
    perm2[9] = n10;
  }
  else{
  //do nothing
  }
  current_line++;
}
```

When I compile this code, it tells me that "line" is undeclared. It also tells me that n1, n2, n3, etc are all undeclared.

How can I fix this?

Comment: In C, you need to declare variables before you can use them, e.g. `int n1;`

Comment: Declare `char line[401]; int n1,n2, n3;`